# Laravel How to get email value on login?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm on Laravel 5.2, and I use `php artisan make:auth`.

when I login successfully (with `email` and password) ,I want to make page url like this : `home/{email}`.

I have changed `protected $redirectTo = '/';` to `protected $redirectTo = 'home/{email}';` in `AuthController.php`. but I think It don't work. page url changes like this `http://localhost:8000/home/%7Bemail%7D`.

How can I do this ?

++

How can I get `email` value on `AuthController` ?

Comment: It seems you're using blade syntax inside your controller.

Comment: @ShubhamoyChakrabarty sorry, I don't understand QQ. I have changed only this line on controller : `protected $redirectTo = '/';` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get value from `email` Request, like this

```
public function __constructor(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $this->redirectTo = "home/{$email}";
}
```

You can use the constructor to replace the value in the redirect

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)

Comment: After executing this command. In the generated AuthController.php

Comment: Is public function __constructor right ? not public function __construct ? `AuthController` already has `public function __construct(){$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);}`.

Comment: And I paste it , nothing happend

Comment: AutoController 
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers; -> use AuthenticatesUsers; -> use RedirectsUsers;


 `trait RedirectsUsers
 {
 public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
            return $this->redirectPath;
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
    }
}`

You simply add the constructor string, as I wrote above, and it will work